# OS (or hostname) specific sections of gitconfig

Tags: git

I have a `gitconfig` file that I share between machines since, for the most part, I want to use the same options on all of my machines. However, there are some things that are specific to the system (credential helper, difftool, etc.).

Is there any way to have a system specific part of the `gitconfig` file (like I can in my `bashrc` or `vimrc` files)?

Comment: Not aware of something like it, but you can replace gitconfig to a machine-relevant version from log-in scripts... yeah :(

Comment: Yeah, I could do something like that, but it would be nasty to maintain that. It would be nice if I could at least source a system specific file inside the .gitconfig file.

Comment: Here is a hack making use of the existing of OS-specific directories (but there should be a trailing slash added!): https://medium.com/doing-things-right/platform-specific-gitconfigs-and-the-wonderful-includeif-7376cd44994d

Answer (score 1):

Yes, git has two user-specific configuration files: `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` and `~/.gitconfig`.  The [git-config man page explains `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)...

> Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty,
>   $HOME/.config/git/config will be used. Any single-valued variable set in this file
>   will be overwritten by whatever is in ~/.gitconfig. It is a good idea not to create
>   this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was
>   added fairly recently.

So copy your generic config into `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` and put your system specific overrides into `~/.gitconfig`.  If you don't have a `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable, you should probably set it to `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.gitconfig`, you can include an "include" section, which will include other files. So you can do

```
[include]
  path = .gitconfig-local
```

Then add a `.gitconfig-local` file on each system containing your system-specific config, which you do not sync across systems.